# Make HTML table cell editable so that updated data goes to backend

Tags: node.js, mongoose, x-editable

I'm trying to make the cells of html table editable, simply click the edit button, input some text and the changes can be sent to server. I saw a plugin called X-Editable but I am unable to implement the documentation into my code. Can anyone please help me with code snippets so that I can implement it.

Comment: What does unable "to implement the documentation into my code" mean? What specific issue did you have when following this? https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html What step did you get to and what happened? Do you really need to have to click an edit button? There are things called HTML forms that have been around forever that do this, they're just not very sophisticated. Do you already have all of the node.js backend set up to accept the form data and save it?

Comment: Yeah I have all things setup, but I am unable to find the thing that whenever I edit the cell, how to update that data into the database as well. This is the point where I am stuck.

Comment: So you have an API built in node.js that will accept a post from your web page, and use that posted data to write to a database?

Comment: Yes! i have to build that